# Memory consumption rampant when using FTP file transfer

Tags: server, ram, ftp

I'm loading files in a newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server using FTP, but every single time I copy a file a new process is created on the server side and the old process not being closed, taking insanely amounts of RAM for transferring a large quantity of small size files. Right now I canceled the transfer because it took 6 GiB of RAM of the 8 GiB of the server.

Closing individual process is a mess, because there is a ton of them, so I restart the server after copying a certain amount of files. Why is happening that?

Comment: How do you check RAM use? What is the output of `free -m` during and after transfer? Which FTP server are you using? How is it configured? [Edit] your question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when moving a lot of files, FTP uses the ram to store cache so that if there is a network connection stutter, it doesn't just fail your job. I would recommend using a type of compression when moving files like a Tar ball.

In regards to your tasks not shutting down, that's really odd, without having eyes on it, I wouldn't be able to say for sure, but it sounds like the job doesn't receive a kill command and or the receiving server didn't send the final "Thank you, I got it all" command to signal FTP to stop.